# c++ std::stringstream gives me weird behavior

Tags: c++, stringstream

The following code give me some unexpected behavior:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

const std::string data1 =
"column1        column2\n"
"1      3\n"
"5      6\n"
"49     22\n";

const std::string data2 =
"column1        column2 column3\n"
"10     20      40\n"
"30     20      10\n";

class IOLoader
{
public:
        // accept an istream and load the next line with member Next()
        IOLoader(std::istream& t_stream) : stream_(t_stream) 
        { 
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) std::getline(stream_, line_);
        };// get rid of the header

        IOLoader(std::istream&& t_stream) : stream_(t_stream) 
        { 
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) std::getline(stream_, line_);
        };// get rid of the header

        void Next()
        {
                // load next line
                if(!std::getline(stream_, line_))
                        line_ = "";
        };

        bool IsEnd()
        { return line_.empty(); };

        std::istream& stream_;
        std::string line_;
};

int main()
{
        for(IOLoader data1_loader = IOLoader((std::stringstream(data1))); !data1_loader.IsEnd(); data1_loader.Next())
        {
                std::cout << data1_loader.line_ << "\n";

                // weird result if the following part is uncommented
                /*
                IOLoader data2_loader = IOLoader(std::stringstream(data2));
                std::cout << data2_loader.line_ << "\n";
                data2_loader.Next();
                std::cout << data2_loader.line_ << "\n";
                */
        }
}
```

I want the class IOLoader to read the string line by line. I get the following result without the commented parts:

```
1       3
5       6
49      22
```

This is completely expected. The problem is what happens when I un-comment the part with data2_loader. Now it gives me:

```
1       3
10      20      40
30      20      10
mn349   22
10      20      40
30      20      10
```

I have no idea what's going on. This is what I originally expected:

```
1       3
10      20      40
30      20      10
5       6
10      20      40
30      20      10
49      22
10      20      40
30      20      10
```

For whatever reason data1 is not read correctly if I create a stringstream with data2. I compile it with g++ 4.9.2. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't take `Next()` without checking that you are not currently at the end of the stream.

Comment: Undefined behavior in **both** cases (even with the commented out part of the code). You are storing a reference to a temporary variable, which ceases to exist at the end of the statement (which, in your case, constructs `IOLoader` instance).

Comment: @alfC actually that for loop does check before calling `Next()`

Comment: @Slava not inside the commented code.

Comment: @alfC I see, missed that part

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to write code just to make compiler stop complaining without understanding what that code do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `IOLoader data1_loader = IOLoader((std::stringstream(data1)));`, you're binding the `IOLoader::stream_` reference member to a *temporary*, since that `std::stringstream(data1)` gets destroyed after the constructor. You're left reading from a dangling reference to destroyed object, which is undefined behavior, and absolutely anything may happen as a result. A simple fix would be to declare both `stringstream` as variables that live for as long as the `IOLoader` needs them, and remove your `IOLoader(std::istream&& t_stream)` constructor because it doesn't actually move `t_stream`, which, as an r-value reference, will generally be a temporary.

```
std::stringstream ss1 {data1};
for(IOLoader data1_loader = IOLoader(ss1); !data1_loader.IsEnd(); data1_loader.Next()){
    std::cout << data1_loader.line_ << "\n";

    std::stringstream ss2 { data2 };
    IOLoader data2_loader = IOLoader(ss2);
    std::cout << data2_loader.line_ << "\n";
    data2_loader.Next();
    std::cout << data2_loader.line_ << "\n";
}
```

If you need `IOLoader` to work very generally with streams that you can't assume ownership of like `std::cin`, then it makes sense to stick with the reference member. Just be aware that the referenced streams need to live for as long as the `stream_` member is being used. Otherwise, if you're only working with `std::stringstream`, it would be easiest to assume ownership of a stream and make `IOLoader::stream_` a value type. For example, you could `std::move` a stream passed by r-value reference to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an rvalue reference and keeping it around is broken, and will almost certainly cause undefined behavior (UB) down the road. I am referring to the following code, which facilitates but does not directly cause UB:

```
IOLoader(std::istream&& t_stream) : stream_(t_stream) 
{ 
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) std::getline(stream_, line_);
};// get rid of the header
```

The constructor makes it possible for the following line to silently trigger UB:

```
for(IOLoader data1_loader = IOLoader((std::stringstream(data1))); !data1_loader.IsEnd(); data1_loader.Next())
```

This line creates a temporary (rvalue) `stringstream` object. Since this is an rvalue, its reference is merrily passed to the constructor of `IOLoader` that accepts rvalue-reference. But the constructor that accepts rvalue-reference does not move anything, and simply stores a reference to the temporary `stringstream`. This is contrary to the normal use of rvalue-references, which is to move the object. By the time the loop body starts, the temporary `stringstream` is already destroyed, and `stream_`  refers to a destroyed object. Using such a reference in `Next()`, or in any other way, is UB.

You can fix this specific instance of the bug by creating a named `stingsstream` object:

```
std::stringstream tmp_stream(data1);
for(IOLoader data1_loader = IOLoader(tmp_stream); !data1_loader.IsEnd(); data1_loader.Next())
```

This will fix the instance but won't fix the core issue. The core issue is the existence of a misleading `&&` constructor. You have two options with the `&&` constructor, either remove it altogether, or make it actually move the `stringstream`:

```
class IOLoader
{
...
        IOLoader(std::stringstream&& t_stream) : saved_stream_(std::move(t_stream)), stream_(saved_stream_)
        { 
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) std::getline(stream_, line_);
        };// get rid of the header

...
        std::stringstream saved_stream_;
        std::istream& stream_;
        std::string line_;
};
```

The disadvantage is that in this case it will work only with `stringstream`, and not with similar types such as `istringstream`. You can make it more generic (a runtime cost of an additional heap allocation) by using templates:

```
class IOLoader
{
public:
....    
        // enable_if avoids regular references, so that we neither prefer this ctor
        // over the other ctor, nor try to move from a regular lvalue reference.
        template <typename Stream, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_reference<Stream>::value>::type>
        IOLoader(Stream&& t_stream) : saved_stream_(std::make_unique<typename std::decay<Stream>::type>(std::move(t_stream))), stream_(*saved_stream_)
        { 
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) std::getline(stream_, line_);
        };
...

        std::unique_ptr<std::istream> saved_stream_;
        std::istream& stream_;
        std::string line_;
};
```

In my opinion this is too complicated for a one-time use and, unless this is going to be used by a lot of code, I'd simply ditch the constructor with the rvalue-reference instead of fixing it.